# Selecting origins instead of objects (Affect origins unchecked)

Tags: objects

When I installed blender (from a flash drive on my new pc) it was working normally for about half an hour and then all of a sudden the origins are being selected instead of objects.  I believe it started happening when I tried adding a curve, that was the first I noticed the issue.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling 3.0 and then tried installing 2.93 but the issue is now present from the very start each time (even in 2.93).  I have no problems on my laptop.  Affect origins is unchecked but when I do check it, the object starts moving the opposite way that I am moving the origin (this in 2.93)

I am running ubuntu mate 20.04 and have not been able to update this machine yet as I can't get ubuntu to recognize the wifi usb that it came with.  Therefore each time I install blender it is being installed from a flash drive.

Thanks in advance, I just bought this fancy new machine literally just for Blender so I'm going a little nutty here :P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting issues with unfinished experimental under development software.

Comment: Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229385/in-2-93-origins-selected-instead-of-objects-with-affect-origins-unchecked