# In 2.93, origins selected instead of objects with affect origins unchecked

Tags: objects

I have tried reinstalling and installing multiple versions (2.93 and 3.0)  and this is happening for me every time right from the beginning.

I had just installed blender on a new computer running ubuntu 20.04 and it was working fine for about half an hour.  I believe the issue started when I added a curve or a path and couldn't select it in object mode.  I then realized I was selecting its origin.  In edit mode i can select the object and manipulate it normally but in object mode the origin is selected instead of the object and affect origins is unchecked.  When I do check it the object moves opposite from the origin.

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally parented the camera to the object (Ctrl+P)? Doing that and checking Affect Only Origins seems to be the only way I can cause the object to move the opposite direction of the origin when I attempt to move the object. If this might be the case, select the camera and the object and un-parent them with Alt+P and select "Clear Parent". Also, any chance you have your camera locked to view?

Comment: The issue starts happening on a fresh install with default settings.  With various distributions.  I’m wondering if it could be my operating system somehow... it happens with both my mouse and tablet.

Comment: Next thing I'd try is making sure your gpu is supported (you can check here) - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/ - and that your drivers are up to date. If that's all in order, and the problem still persists - and this is a longshot- uninstall your tablet (or at least make sure blender doesn't recognize it) and go in mouse only. I only say this because I've seen a couple issues recently (one last night actually) where tablet drivers have caused issues in blender, although that caused a white screen at startup and was also affecting adobe software.

Comment: On that note, I'll add, any chance you have a Huion Tablet?

Comment: I've been using the same tablet (wacom) with blender on my laptop for months now with no problems, however I haven't been able to update my new system yet because I can't get ubuntu to see my wifi dongle so perhaps it's a driver issue.  graphics cards is nvidia rtx 2060 so no issue there.

Comment: Yeah. I don't really have any other guesses - but driver issues (outdated and the like) are known cause of "funky" behavior from time to time. Hopefully you can get your system updated so you can see if the problem is still there afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for all the help folks, switched OS and updated my nvidia driver.  All seems to be well now.